# Music Player Timer

Tags: swift, uislider, audio-player

```
func configurePlayer() {
  player.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1), queue: dispatch_get_main_queue()) { (CMTime) -> Void in
    var timeNow = Int(self.player.currentTime().value) / Int(self.player.currentTime().timescale)
    var currentMins = timeNow / 60
    var currentSec = timeNow % 60
    var duration: NSString = "\(currentMins):\(currentSec)"
    self.durationOutlet.text = duration // <<- Green line here
    self.sliderOutlet.value = Float(timeNow)
  }
}
```

I'm creating a music player and everything works fine, but it crashes when I try to get the duration timer to count or the slider to animate. It works fine for 2 seconds, but then it crashes. I call this method in `viewDidLoad`. There are no errors at all except a green line where I pointed above.

Comment: Did you make sure the player and the playerItem are ready to play?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with `durationOutlet` outlet.

So make sure that `durationOutlet` is connected properly from storyboard.

[HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=71770174551704190400) is sample project for more Info.

Answer (score 0):

It crushes when you convert time.value which is CMTimeValue which is Int64 to Int. It only crushes when you use 32 bit device. So instead Int I used Int64 and it worked for me. I'm still not sure why it works, though. So i suggest you try something like this:
`let timeNow  = Int64(time.value) / Int64(time.timescale)`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing how the player is set up. I don't believe you can stream a file hosted on a remote server with AVAudioPlayer. For that you would have to use AVPlayer. You might want to add some logging to print out what is in timeNow to see what value it has when it breaks. If you are using an AVPlayer, you need to check that the status of the AVPlayerItem is ReadyToPlay. Try something like this:

```
player.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1), queue: dispatch_get_main_queue()) { (CMTime) -> Void in

    if self.player.currentItem?.status == .ReadyToPlay {

      var timeNow = Int(self.player.currentTime().value) / Int(self.player.currentTime().timescale)

      var currentMins = timeNow / 60
      var currentSec = timeNow % 60

      var duration: NSString = "\(currentMins):\(currentSec)"

      self.durationOutlet.text = duration // <<- Green line here

      self.sliderOutlet.value = Float(timeNow)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a code in swift to update slider when player is in play mode.**

```
player.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1), queue: dispatch_get_main_queue()) { (CMTime) -> Void in
            if self.player.currentItem?.status == .ReadyToPlay {
                let thePlayerItem : AVPlayerItem = self.player.currentItem!
                let duration : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(thePlayerItem.duration);
                let time : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime());
                self.sliderVideoPlayer.value = Float (time / duration);
            }
        }
```